# Interacting with the user: Programming R in order to ask questions to the user

Tags: r

I am trying to create a model in which R asks some questions to the user, and the user answer to them.

I have already create two vector. In one there are numbers and in the other the same numbers written in character:

```
a <- 1:10
words <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")
> a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> words
 [1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"  "five"  "six"   "seven" "eight" "nine"  "ten"
```

I would like to create a script that, for each item in `a`, automatically asks a question like: `1?` then `2?`, and so on. The user answer, in order to go to the next number, needs to answer `one`, then `two` and so on.

If the user makes a mistake the program needs to be able to remember the mistake and ask the question again after n questions. I think I should use while command and `readline` but I am not sure about that.

Comment: John I tried to make the question the clearer I could but it's you to have to make the final adjustment. I may change the meaning as I may have misunderstood the real question...

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine:

```
test <- winDialogString("Please insert a value", default="")
```

then type, say, "Hello".

```
> test
[1] "Hello"
```

A simple example for your desired loop would be:

```
a <- ""
test <- 1L
while(a!=test){
  a <- winDialogString(paste0(test,"?"), default="")
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood the question before

```
a <- 1L:10L
test <- c("one","two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")
res <- ""

for(i in seq_along(a)){
  if(is.null(res)) break
  while(res!=test[i]){
    res <- winDialogString(paste0(a[i],"?"), default="")
    if(is.null(res)) break 
  }
}
```

The above version stops the execution when the user press `cancel`. Instead if you want the user to finish the exercise the following

```
a <- 1L:10L
test <- c("one","two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")
res <- NULL

for(i in seq_along(a))
  while(is.null(res) || res!=test[i])
    res <- winDialogString(paste0(a[i],"?"), default="")
```

keeps asking for a solution (for all the number 1 to 10) until you respond correctly, and clicking `cancel` won't have any effect.

Comment: A simple alternative is the `menu` command.

Comment: @joran yeah, possibly. But the OP didn't mention anything about choices, just open questions.

Comment: I'm blindly guessing from the name that `winDialog*` is WindowsOS -only?  In which case the rest of us are back to using `readline` or writing a Tcl GUI.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm pretty sure there is a Tcl/Tk equivalent for window based functionality, like progress bar and win dialog. I'll see if I can edit now, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `menu` can be graphical (tcl/tk) or not, and should be cross-platform. For this case, though, you may just want `readline`.